# What is the difference between "note" and "notice"?

Tags: verbs, word-difference

Can I say something like:

1. Please **note** that the ocean is pink.
2. Please **notice** that the elephant is small.

Which is the correct one? Or are both correct? Or wrong?

Answer (score 9):

To *notice* X is to acknowledge that X is in your sight, hearing, etc.

To *note* X means that X is important and you should remember it.  If you have a physical notebook it can mean to actually write X down.

You may be expected to specifically recall something you noted or that someone asked you to note, whereas *notice* is more used to just "keep something in mind."

If something is really important, a speaker or writer may use *note* over *notice* for emphasis and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

These two terms are incorrectly used interchangeably when there is actually a significant difference between them.

**"Please notice X"** is used to draw someone's immediate attention to something which is often a sensory or perceptual effect. You are guiding the viewer's perception to something in particular. A tour guide might say "Please notice the design of this building", inviting the viewers' gaze to the building so that he might point out something of interest about it.

**"Please note X"** is used to tell somebody that they should make a conscious effort to remember the piece of information X because it is somehow important. It is less to do with immediate sensory/perceptual information and more to do with committing something to memory (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

**Note** comes (indirectly) from Latin meaning “mark” (as in write down), and **notice** also from Latin meaning something like “know this”. The latter came to mean something printed in the 19th century.

Modern usage often conflates the two; the meanings are closely connected, the chief difference being that a “note” is a physical record of something, but “knowing” relates to *awareness* of that thing.

Think “words” versus “information”.

Answer (score 0):

They are synonyms. "**Please note**" is more common.

Comment: "Note", unlike "Notice" can be used to suggest that someone remember.  I would more likely say "Please note that there will be a test at the end of the week" than "Please notice that there will be a test at the end of the week."

Comment: I don't think it is correct to say that they are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of giving some useful advice or recommendation, to me, to note something is to notice and remember it as something important.